# wp7 xdocument xml node c#

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7

I need to extract an XML node of this XML document:

http://api.chartlyrics.com/apiv1.asmx/SearchLyricDirect?artist=michael%20jackson&song=bad

I am unable to figure this out. Below is the current code I use to read in the XML from that url.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.DownloadStringCompleted += HttpsCompleted;
    wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://api.chartlyrics.com/apiv1.asmx/SearchLyricDirect?artist=michael%20jackson&song=bad"));
}

private void HttpsCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)
    {
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result, LoadOptions.None);
        this.textBox1.Text = xdoc.LastNode.ToString();
    }
}
```

How can I access the node `lyric` from within the XML document from the provided URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Linq To Xml for this kind of scenario.
Note, that there is a namespace (`xmlns="http://api.chartlyrics.com/"`) in the xml result.

A really basic example could be :

```
void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)
    {
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result, LoadOptions.None);
        var lyric = xdoc.Descendants(XName.Get("Lyric","http://api.chartlyrics.com/")).FirstOrDefault();

        this.textBox1.Text = lyric.Value;
    }
}
```